# What image viewer / browser will allow me to run a custom script on all selected images?

Tags: linux, images, script

I'd like to find an image browsing software that I can use in Linux. I need to see thumbnails of all the image files in a given directory and run a custom script on all the selected images.

I've been looking at xnview, but I haven't found the option to run a custom script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gThumb with the File list tools extension should be capable of this.

Comment: Just installed gThumb. I could not see the File list extension, but the Hot Keys option provide exactly the functionality I need. Thanks!